# Access Violation using XMMatrix and std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm currently having a problem in my project where I'm trying to get a Dx11 running.

My error is:
*Unhandled exception at 0x00FC266D in 3DTestProject.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.*

The Crash Occurs in my Model.cpp IN Model::Render() at this line:
`cb.mWorld = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(aOrientation);`

Because of the implementation I have to send it as a const reference in Render()

```
const DirectX::XMMATRIX& aOrientation
```

Called from Instance
`m_pModel->Update();`

My header for Instance looks like this:

```
class Instance 
{
public:
  Instance();
  Instance(Model* aModel);
  ~Instance();

  void Update();
  void Render(Camera* aCamera);

private:

  DirectX::XMMATRIX m_Orientation;
};
```

My guess is it is because I store my instances in Scene.h as a std::vector and I don't know how to solve it.

```
std::vector<Instance> m_vecInstances;
```

Comment: Did you check if `m_pModel` was `NULL`?

Comment: Yes, I do it's really random.

Answer (score 0):

Changing these lines and using XMFLOAT4X4 instead seems to work at this point.

```
const DirectX::XMFLOAT4X4 aOrientation
```

and

`cb.mWorld = DirectX::XMMatrixTranspose(XMLoadFloat4x4(&aOrientation));`